# Preventing text to overlap

Tags: html, css

Below is my code, my goal is to prevent the div with an id "description" to overlap on the div with class name "container_display". How can I achieve this? I want the second div to show at the bottom of the image.

```css
#container_display {
    position: relative;
}

#container_display img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container_display">
    <img src="image1.png" />
    <img src="image2.png" />
</div>

<div id="description">TEXT HERE</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a visual to make clear what you want to achieve? Sounds like a job for `bottom: 0;` on the description

Comment: Here I uploaded it https://i.imgur.com/Ms5fgog.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a height for the container, because the absolutely positioned elements are not considered to occupy width or height in the container.

Details [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute):

> absolute
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout

```css
#container_display {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
}

#container_display img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container_display">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KzWG55K/Pokemon-PNG-Image.png" />
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/x8r33KL/Pokemon-Free-Download-PNG-1.png" />
</div>

<div id="description">TEXT HERE</div>
```

There is one way to "hack it", which is to place one static image there and make it `visibility: hidden`, which is to occupy space, but not visible, and the `position` back to `static`:

```css
#container_display {
  position: relative;
}

#container_display img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
}

#container_display .spacer {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div id="container_display">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KzWG55K/Pokemon-PNG-Image.png" />
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/x8r33KL/Pokemon-Free-Download-PNG-1.png" />
  <img class="spacer" src="https://i.ibb.co/x8r33KL/Pokemon-Free-Download-PNG-1.png" />
</div>

<div id="description">TEXT HERE</div>
```

Comment: This works like a charm. I had to do some adjustment though.  var background_height = $('#background_display_main').height();
    $('#container_display').css('height', background_height+'px');

Comment: @PhilGreene please see one hack added to occupy space but just not visible... then you don't have to use JS. You probably want to use the "tallest" image for it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this:

```
#container_display img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

You could also add a break between both divs to create space between them, like this:

```
<div id="container_display">
<img src="image1.png" />
<img src="image2.png" />
</div> 
<br>
<div id="description">TEXT HERE</div>
```